# Maths Symbol From Variable

Tags: python, variables, math

I have a challenge at school, but i am stuck with a small bit of my code.

Here's what I have; what I'm missing is how to finish the `answer =` line:

```
while (questions <= 9):
    randoms()
    print("What is: ", num1, symbol, num2,"?:")
    uanswer = int(input())
    answer = 
    if uanswer == answer:
        correct = correct + 1
    else:
        incorrect = incorrect + 1
    questions = questions + 1
```

The variables `num1`, `num2` and `symbol` are randomly generated, `num1` and `num2` are both integers, and `symbol` is either `'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'` or `'/'` I was wondering how to use these to get an answer to an equation.

For example, `num1` is `50`, `symbol` is `'-'`, and `num2` is `25`. How would I use the variables to get the answer `25`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clean way to do this is to create a mapping from symbols to functions.

The only question is, what is the function behind the `+` operator?

The answer is in the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) module: `a + b` is `operator.add(a, b)`, and so on. So:

```
import operator

symbols = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.floordiv
}
```

I'm assuming here that you want `100 / 3` to be `33`, not `33.333333333333336`. If I'm wrong, use `truediv` instead of `floordiv` above. (See [Numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers) in the tutorial for an introduction to the difference, with links to more details.)

Anyway, now, you can do this:

```
answer = symbols[symbol](num1, num2)
```

---

Even if you didn't have `operator`, you could always build a function for each operator:

```
symbols = {
    '+': (lambda a, b: a + b),
    '-': (lambda a, b: a - b),
    '*': (lambda a, b: a * b),
    '/': (lambda a, b: a // b)
}
```

This may come in handy if you want to extend your language to a symbol that doesn't have a matching operator in Python.

---

If your maths language is a strict subset of Python's expression language (which it may not be—notice that the symbol `'/'` maps to the Python operator `//` if you want integers), and you're sure that you're never going to extend it in a way that isn't (e.g., using `^` for exponentiation), and you're sure that you will never be using any numbers or symbols that you didn't generate yourself, it may be simpler to just build a Python expression and [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) it:

```
expr = '{} {} {}'.format(num1, symbol, num2)
answer = eval(expr)
```

However, you should always be careful about using `eval`; if the clean thing to do is simple enough for you to write, and to read and understand later, it's almost always a better answer.

Comment: Great comprehensive post, with eval as a last resort option... I like it very much.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much! Your a life saver, as you can probably tell im not that advanced in python yet :P but thanks dude :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is creating conditonals and check the symbol..

```
if symbol=='-':
   res = num1 - num2
elif symbol=='+':
   res = num1 + num2
```